# Notepad++ Modify lines in xml file

Tags: notepad++

i have a XML file and i need to modify the lines inside the tags:

```
<category><![CDATA[
            BOY/casual shoes
        ]]></category>
<brand_name><![CDATA[
            KLIN
        ]]></brand_name>
```

Basically i want to find all categories and brands but they must be each in one line, optionally without space inside:

```
<category><![CDATA[BOY/casual shoes]]></category>
<brand_name><![CDATA[KLIN]]></brand_name>
```

Is there an option or trick in Notepad++ to do the job for all lines at once in the XML?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Toto I find and tried, but was for each tag at a time, not for all tags at once.

Comment: @Toto One step to remove space, two steps to add a tag in one line.